# Send POST values and get response using HttpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net

I have this php file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['message']))
{
    $msg = $_POST['message'];

    if($msg == "age")
        echo "I am 18";
    else if($msg == "name")
        echo "my name is Jonathan";
    else
        echo "I do not know";

}

?>
```

I want to make a HttpWebRequest in VB.NET such that if I send the value "age" from a TextBox:
[image]

To get this following msgbox:

[image]


I tried something like this :

```
Public Sub SendPostData(ByVal site As String, ByVal message As String)

    Dim request As WebRequest
    request = WebRequest.Create(site)
    Dim response As WebResponse
    Dim postData As String = "message=" + message
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)


    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = data.Length

    Dim stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    stream.Close()

    response = request.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())


    MsgBox(sr.ReadToEnd)


End Sub
```

**and I got this :** 
[image]

Any idea why i'm getting that instead of one of the 3 possible message in the php file? ("I am 18", "my name is Jonathan", or "I do not know") ?
Please note that I tested the php normally from a html form and it worked, so I wonder why it's not working from the program.

Comment: can you tell which site is it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the request using fiddler?  Maybe there is something that is not being sent correctly.

Comment: theGD, i think you didn't understand my question

Comment: @Wade73, i think I didn't understand your answer

Comment: I was going to do what Wade73 was suggesting. You should use a plug-in called Live HTTP headers or a simirlar one in order to see what data your browser sends to the website. So you can simulate it. If you can give me the address of your website, I can do that for you as I told.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.  Fiddler is a HTTP sniffer and it shows your HTTP request, where you can check the headers, posted values, etc...  Here is the link - http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: ahh okay i get the idea right now! Thanks a lot guys! I will give it a try!

Comment: @theGD thanks a lot bro, the thing is that i'm not working on a website right now, i'm working on my local server, and all i'm using the above mentioned codes. so if you wanna help me, i hope you can test the above codes for me, please? Thanks a lot

Comment: @JonathanHugh - can you show the `Send Post` button click handler code?

Comment: The reason was because of the webserver i was using. I changed a webhost and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting WHAT you're getting is because you have stated that the FORM content is of a "x-www-form-urlencoded" format AND you have used the POST method and one supposes that whatever is in the cookie (cookie data) is the information that you passed through but it has been encoded by the server before sending.

I'm not sure how but you should be able to un-encode it too.
Alternatively you could use GET as opposed to POST and also if there is only going to be TEXT and no SPECIAL symbols or characters which ACTUALLY require encoding, then maybe you could use a different CONTENT-TYPE that CORRECTLY identifies the type of content that you are sending...

The following page at W3.org is good reading and explains the differences between the various bits and pieces and how they interact with one another and with the server too.

Forms
(
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

How Forms are processed(
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3)

Answer (score 2):

I am experience .net software and knows php also

Never user httpwebrequest and httpwebresponse, 'coz both are out dated

here is the link check properly
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It uses `WebRequest` and `WebResponse`, add references `System.Net` and `System.Web` in your code

And target framework must be 4.0, 4.5 or higher but not to select name containing Client Profile

Answer (score 2):

I have used WebClient to solve a similar problem where i needed to use parameters in the HTTP POST. For your case, a simplified solution like this could help if you play well around with your code; Assuming you have a textbox to capture the age, you could pass it as a variable to the url using this code;

```
Using client As New WebClient
        Dim postdata = client.UploadString(url, "age")
        MsgBox(postdata) 
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered doing something like this?

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Action As String = "http://www.mywebsite.com/myaction.php"
        PostMessage("submit", "Paul", Action)
    End Sub
    Sub PostMessage(ByVal Type As String, ByVal Value As String, ByVal Action As String)
        Dim TmpFile As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\post.html"
        Using WB As New WebBrowser
            Dim HTML As String = _
                "<html><body>" &
                "<form method=""post"" action=""" & Action & """>" &
                "<input type=""" & Type & """ value=""" & Value & """ />" &
                "</form>" &
                "</body></html>"
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(TmpFile, HTML, False)
            WB.Navigate(TmpFile)
            Do : Application.DoEvents()
            Loop Until WB.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            WB.Document.GetElementById(Type).InvokeMember(Type)
            Do : Application.DoEvents()
            Loop Until WB.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        End Using
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TmpFile)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Using WebBrowser is a little bit heavy... so of course I would stick with my code, using Http Request that works on all web servers EXCEPT mine. The thing is I wonder how such a problem can be solve from the Server side, not from my side, as I have no problems with my code. I remind you, it works fine on other web servers! Do we need to edit something in php.ini ? I don't know.. just wondering..

Comment: Why even use post message or php anyways? Why don't you just use a sql connection or something.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to change this line:

```
Dim postData As String = "message=" + message
```

to:

```
Dim postData As String = "message=" & message
```

use `"&"` instead of `"+"`

Regards...